# Xcode 3.2.2 and LLVM version 1.0.2 failing

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 3.2.2 and I am trying to use LLVM version 1.0.2 as a compiler.

When I do that, I see the error

> **Library not found for -lgcc**
>
> **Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1**

How do I solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use LLVM to compile iPhone apps in 3.2. You'll need to use GCC.

Comment: Because Xcode is used to build Mac apps, which can be built with LLVM.

Comment: correcting... apparently (theory) in practice 3.2.3 has so many problems that I had to install 3.2.2 again. I am not sure how Apple want us to use 3.2.3... lots of problems with applications you already have designed for 3.2 and below.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it seems that you can use LLVM on Xcode 3.2.3. I've just downloaded it now and LLVM works!!!!